# When can Scala's implicitly return null?

Tags: scala, typeclass, implicit, shapeless

I was recently surprised when invocations of Scala's `implicitly` was returning null during runtime.  I had thought that was unlikely, given that the code shouldn't compile if no implicit instance was available in implicit scope.  When is implicitly allowed to return null?  Is this a compiler limitation, or is this expected behavior?

Here's some context, if it helps.  I'm using shapeless to derive typeclass instances for persisting arbitrary nested case classes.  I thought it would be helpful to use implicitly in the nested case classes to check if a typeclass instance could be derived, as it can be unclear where to start looking if the nested case class is large.

So, for example, if I was trying to persist:

```
case class Foo(bar: Bar, baz: Baz)
```

and the compiler couldn't derive an instance for my formatter `MyFormatter[Foo]`, I started doing something like the following:

```
case class Bar(i: Int, q: Qux)
object Bar {
  implicit val formatter = implicitly[MyFormatter[Bar]]
}
```

expecting the compiler to tell me that it couldn't find an implicit instance of `MyFormatter[Bar]`.

Instead, this was a terrible idea, and my code compiled (when it shouldn't have, as no typeclass instance for Qux could be derived) and `Bar.formatter` was null at runtime.

Comment: There's something wrong with the code relevant to `MyFormatter`. _Something_ is making that implicit, but it's impossible to say what without seeing it. The Scala compiler won't magically create one that is `null` on its own.

Comment: I hear what you're saying: but short of a definition like `implicit val oyVey: MyFormatter[Bar] = null` (which I promise I didn't do) what would make that possible?

Comment: I don't know without seeing the code. `implicitly` grants no magic. You could try `println(scala.reflect.runtime.universe.reify(implicitly[MyFormatter[Foo]]))` to see where it is being resolved from.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your implicit definition is recursive.

```
scala> class C ; object C { implicit val cs: List[C] = implicitly[List[C]] }
defined class C
defined object C

scala> C.cs
res0: List[C] = null
```

Not only is cs in scope, but object C is in implicit scope for List[C].

Also, it's preferred to specify the type of implicits; sometimes it is necessary for inference to work; and someday it will be required.